# Symfony Error when loading a Profile Form

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I'm currently getting this error when trying to load an edit form for my Profile entity.

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Profile, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Profile.
```

I was Wondering if anyone knows how to fit this.  I'm using a Profile controller and the User and Profile have a OneToOne relationship with each other.

Here is my code for the Profile controller that loads that form

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/edit", name="profile_edit")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $profileRepository = $em->getRepository(Profile::class);

    $user = $this->getUser();

    $profile = $profileRepository->getProfileByUserId($user->getId());

    $form = $this->createForm(ProfileType::class, $profile);

    $form->handlerequest($request);

    if( $form_.isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $firstname = $form->get('firstname')->getData();
        $lastname = $form->get('lastname')->getData();

        $description = $form->get('description')->getData();

        $profile->setFirstname($firstname);
        $profile->setLastName($lastname);
        $profile->setDescription($description);

        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('flash-profileeditted', 'You\'ve successfully updated your profile.');
        $this->redirectToRoute('profile_page');
    }

    return $this->render('profile/edit.html.twig', ['form' => createForm(), 'profile' => $profile]);
}
```

And here is my ProfileType::class

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [ 'label' => 'Firstname', 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
    ->add('lastname', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Lastname', 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
    ->add('description', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'In Your Own Words', 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
    ->add('user')
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Edit Profile', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-info']]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Profile'
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'appbundle_profile';
}
```

Not Sure what else to include here, hopefully everything is ok and the solution can be found within this code.

I should also point out that I am using FOSUserBundle.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I finally found out what was happening.  I was using the Profile Repository to find a user by their id, but that was returning an array.  So what I had to do is use this code:

```
  $profile = $profileRepository->findOneByUser($user->getId());
```

This actually returns the Object as an AppBundle\Entity\Profile object which can then be used to populate the form.